# Is it possible to display 'special' characters in tcsh prompt running on gnome-terminal?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, tcsh

I'd like to know whether its possible to do special characters like so [image: so] in tcsh prompt running on gnome-terminal.

I remember seeing a 'skelton-head' in someone's prompt a while back. Things like that. you get the idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print a skull and cross bones if the font you're using includes it by doing:

```
/usr/bin/printf '\u2620\n'
```

then you can copy and paste the character in the position you want it in your prompt definition, for example:

```
set prompt = "%U%m%u:%B%~%b% ☠ # "
```

You can make your prompt persistent by adding that assignment to your `~/.tcshrc` file.